# RGB/Hexdecimal color to Decimal Value

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

lets say that i want to convert the color `#FFFFFF` to Decimal value: `16777215` , or `RGB(255,255,255)` to `16777215`, how can i do it(`C#` or `VB.net`)?

i have to convert the RGB/Hexdecimal color to Decimal, because i want to convert the color to Decimal and then convert the Decimal to bytes (`BitConverter.GetBytes(DecimalValue)` and the write the bytes into memoryAdress,
this website converts any color to Decimal : http://www.mathsisfun.com/hexadecimal-decimal-colors.html

(i can convert the SWF file to FLA file and the take a look at the function, But I'm sure that there are better ways and easier ways)

Comment: Is your color, #FFFFFF, expressed as a string?

Comment: Simplifying the question, all you really want is to be able to go from hex -> decimal. In the RGB(255, 255, 255) case, you'd have some extra steps for string/number manipulation to end up with the full 0xFFFFFF.

Comment: @Jim Mischel  yes, or as system.drawing.color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dim decValue as String = Convert.ToInt32("FFFFFF", 16)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ColorTranslator`:

```
String knownColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.White);  //returns "White" which is reversible through FromHtml()
```

...or

```
String hexColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(255, 100, 100, 100));  //returns the hex value
```

And the inverse:

```
Color myColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("FFFFFF");
```

To get to an Int32, just `Convert` it:

```
Int32 iColor = Convert.ToInt32("FFFFFF");
```

This gives you both coming and going options...simply combine them to get the desired result in whatever direction you are going.

Comment: Note that, in your first example, and all examples that are html named colors your `hexColor` string will have `"White"` and not the hex number representation.

Answer (score 3):

I would go with

```
int.Parse("FFFFFF", System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

RGB = (R*65536)+(G*256)+B , (when R is RED, G is GREEN and B is BLUE)